# Issue with startitem in Sitecore

Tags: url, sitecore

We have four different environments - dev VMs, dev, QA and prod. All environments have the following setting for the "website" site:

```
<site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" 
rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" database="master" 
domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="false" 
htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" 
xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" 
enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" 
disableClientData="false" loginPage="/" hostName="www.site.com" 
enableFallback="true" enforceVersionPresence="true"/>.
```

So on VM and prod, www.site.com/en/home/press and www.site.com/en/press work.

But on dev and QA, www.site.com/en/home/press works but www.site.com/en/press doesn't work. (Works with startItem but gets a 404 without it).

This is happening with ISAPI enabled and disabled both (no exceptions).

I am not sure what is going on here or where else to look except to make sure that my start item is in good shape which it seems to be.

What can I do to resolve this? If you need more information please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: "but www.site.com/en/press doesn't work" - what error do you get?

Comment: I updated my question with the error. I get a 404 on pages that don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at the:

"linkManager" tag in the web.config, there is a property called:

languageEmbedding: asNeeded | always | never

which could be set differently on those solutiuons.

Comment: I'd recommend *never* having this set at 'asNeeded'

Comment: Yeah that just seems like a strange setting. I usually go with Never, but then I don't use Sitecore language features that much.

Comment: We use language features so this needs to be set to "always". As of right now this is set to "always" in all of our environments.

Comment: Setting to "always" is not required for multi-language site support.  Sitecore stores a language cookie and defaults to whatever language is found there when the user returns to the site.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Multi-Language website it is recommended to go with 

languageEmbedding: always
Advantages :

- Some time in IE8 the Language cookie is destroyed, because of that
  the language displayed is change randomly.(We have faced this issue
  in our environment) LanguageEmbadding : Always will keep the Information and will work without any Issue.
- If you have set asNeeded then First time the Language will be displayed and next time onward it will be hidden. But this will create issue with Google Analytics. In GA you will have 2 diff URL with same page content so your analysis will be unnecessarily divided in to 2 pages.

And Yes you can check if there is any difference is Config files. As Mentioned by Martijn you can use the www.site.com/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx Copy the Config, compare it using any file compare tool like WinMerge etc.

What is the Hierarchy in your project?
Sitecore-Content-home-Press or 
Sitecore-Content-home-Home-Press?

In my project the setting you have mentioned has database = web.

Answer (score 1):

I can't add a comment, but as Martijn says you need to compare the configs. Now this should be very easy since you should be using config include files and so the changes between the environments should be very minimal. If you are not using them then you should start using them, it makes life much easier to figure out the differences from default Sitecore installation and will also make your upgrades much easier in the future. Or maybe you are using them for the other environments and that is what is causing the issue?

[All About web.config Include Files with the Sitecore ASP.NET CMS](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/All-About-web-config-Include-Files-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx)

As for comparing the configs, use a file comparison tool like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) as already metioned, that should weed out the differences much more easily.

Also, as Maulik says, default config has: `database="web" content="master"`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like config differences. Compare the live configs by using www.site.com/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx. This way you can see the actual config which also includes all your /app_config/include/ files

Comment: The config is huge. Would you recommend that I look in any special areas in the config files?